# Pass a viewmode edit/add to the durandaljs wizard

Tags: durandal

https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-2.0/blob/gh-pages/app/masterDetail/wizard/index.js

When I look at this wizard I ask myself how can I pass a variable - like the mode being in an edit or add-mode for the wizard - to the index.js which creates step1, step2 and step3.

I do not see where I could pass this data because the index.js which is the main-wizard holding all steps is created by durandal dynamically.

So how can I pass data to the index.js so that I can decide wether I run the service.create() or service.edit() function to get different data etc...

**UPDATE**

```
define(['durandal/app','plugins/dialog', 'knockout', 'services/dataservice', 'plugins/router', 'moment'], function (app, dialog, ko, dataservice, router, moment) {

    var SchoolyearDialog = function () {

        var self = this;
        self.activeScreen = ko.observable('viewmodels/SchoolyearBrowser'); // set the schoolyear browser as default module 

        app.on('startWizard').then(function (obj) {
            self.activeScreen(obj.moduleId);
        });       

        app.on('dialog:close').then(function (options) {
            dialog.close(self, options );
        });

        self.closeDialog = function () {            
            dialog.close(self, { isSuccess: false });
        }
    }
    SchoolyearDialog.show = function () {

        return dialog.show(new SchoolyearDialog());
    };
```

The SchoolyearDialog module is in control which screen is shown. And the SchoolyearDialog has subscribed to the startWizard event. The startWizard event is fired by pressing the createWizard button. There is also an editWizard button which would fire another event like startWizardEdit. Either the activeScreen is set to the default module id: 'viewmodels/SchoolyearBrowser' or to
the module id: 'viewmodels/SchoolyearWizard' which loads the wizard

Is it possible somehow to pass the activeScreen property a value (viewMode) and retrieve it inside the wizard module holding the steps?

Comment: Whos's in control of the initial wizard mode? The example might not be ideal, because it's a) returning a singleton and you probably looking for a constructor function instead and b) it's activated via a child router which limits what you can pass into the `activate` function.

Comment: I have updated my init question with more information. Thanks Rainer :)

Comment: Pretty good use case, so I went ahead and created a new example.

Comment: "Pretty good use case..." because its real life sample ;-) life writes best stories hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've update the initial example slightly, so that it better fits this use case.
In `index.js` you'd have to create an instance of the wizard, which you then pass into the `activeScreen` observable (you can opt for an activator here as well if you need the full Durandal event lifecyle).

Take a look at http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#master-detail/wizard2 to see it in action.

**Index.js**
https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-2.0/blob/gh-pages/app/masterDetail/wizard2/index.js

```
define(['durandal/activator', 'knockout', './wizard'], function( activator, ko, Wizard ) {

    var ctor = function() {
        this.activeScreen = ko.observable();
    };

    ctor.prototype.activate = function( wizId ) {

        // Get wizard data based on wizId from the backend
        var json =
            {"id": "wizard001", "mode": "create", "steps": [
                {"id": "s001", "name": "step one", "props": {"prop1": "a", "prop2": "b"}},
                {"id": "s002", "name": "step twoe", "props": {"prop3": "a", "prop4": "b"}},
                {"id": "s003", "name": "step three", "props": {"prop5": "a", "prop6": "b"}},
                {"id": "s004", "name": "step four", "props": {"prop7": "a", "prop8": "b"}},
                {"id": "s005", "name": "step five", "props": {"prop9": "a", "prop10": "b"}}
            ]};

        this.activeScreen(new Wizard(json));
    };

    return ctor;

});
```

**wizard.js**
https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-2.0/blob/gh-pages/app/masterDetail/wizard2/wizard.js

```
define(['durandal/activator', './step', 'knockout'], function( activator, Step, ko ) {

    var ctor = function( options ) {

        ...

        this.init(this._options);

        this.stepsLength = ko.computed(function() {
            return this.steps().length;
        }, this);

        this.hasPrevious = ko.computed(function() {
            return this.step() > 0;
        }, this);

        this.hasNext = ko.computed(function() {
            return (this.step() < this.stepsLength() - 1);
        }, this);

    };

    ...

    ctor.prototype.init = function( options ) {
        var json = options;

        this.id(json.id);
        this.mode(json.mode);

        this.steps(createSteps(options.steps));

        function createSteps ( steps ) {
            var result = [];
            $.each(steps, function( idx, obj ) {
                result.push(new Step(obj));
            });
            return result;
        }

        this.activateStep();

    };

    return ctor;
});
```

**step.js**
https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-2.0/blob/gh-pages/app/masterDetail/wizard2/step.js

```
define(['knockout'], function( ko ) {

    var Property = function( id, val ) {
        this.id = id,
            this.val = ko.observable(val);
    };

    var ctor = function( options ) {
        this._options = options || {};
        this.id = ko.observable();
        this.name = ko.observable();
        this.props = ko.observableArray([]);

        this.init(this._options)
    };

    ctor.prototype.init = function( options ) {

        this.id(options.id || '');
        this.name(options.name || '');

        this.props(createProperties(options.props));

        function createProperties (props) {
            var result = [];
            $.each(props, function( prop, val ) {
                result.push(new Property(prop, val));
            });

            return result;
        }

    };
    return ctor;

});
```

Feel free to fork and I'm taking pull requests ;-)

Comment: I am bit confused why you pass the wizId to the activate function because you never read the variable? If I understand you correctly I just have to say: this.activeScreen(new Wizard('edit')); or this.activeScreen(new Wizard('create')); depending which button was pressed edit/create and then the event fired... right?

Comment: ok I just did it as I asked before and it works. In my wizard I can differentiate wether to do a create or edit service call. Thanks again Rainer.

Comment: It's an example ;-). The reason why there's an `init` function is that you could now either run `init` in the constructor function or if you use an activator through `activate`. The example above would allow you to read an wizard state from the backend by making an async call. In your case your only interested in two states `edit`or  `create` so `new Wizard('create|edit')`is all that's required ... at least for now.

Comment: "read an wizard state from backend..." I am confused by this. Do you have a scenario when someone would like to read the wizard state from backend? What means backend for you in our context? clientDataService.js or on serverside?

Comment: Think of a wizard factory that allows a) creating multiple wizards, each with it's own steps/properties and b) saving/reloading the wizard state (filled out steps/props so far) to the server. As said it's a contrived example that has parts in it that doesn't apply to your scenario.