# Durandal widgets, dynamic templated parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, widget, durandal

I'm building a wizard widget with Durandal, and I'd like to use it like so:

```
        <div data-bind="wizard: options">
            <!-- Step 1 -->
            <span data-part="step-header-1">
                Step 1
            </span>
            <div data-part="step-content-1">
                step content here
            </div>

            <!-- Step 2 -->
            <span data-part="step-header-2">
                Step 2
            </span>
            <div data-part="step-content-2">
                step content here
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the actual widget (cut down for brevity):

```
<div class="wizard-container">

    <ul class="steps" data-bind="foreach: steps">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="html: heading"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- ko foreach: steps -->
    <div class="wizard-step" data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
        <div data-bind="html: content">

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

</div>
```

I've sort of gotten it working, using jQuery to grab the data-parts, assign the data-part's inner HTML to a property on my step model, and then use the html-binding to bind the content to each step. This works on the DOM side of things, but doing it this way means that my step content won't get data-bound.. I am pretty sure it's because I use the html binding, which does not bind the content.

Is there a way to do this with Durandal widgets, without separating each step into a new view?

Comment: Do you want them all showing at the same time, or change depending on which step you are on?

Comment: @PWKad all of that is working already, like I said I cut down the code for brevity - the only issue is that any data-bind in my step-content won't be bound, since the entire content is being loaded using Knockout's HTML-binding, which does not apply bindings to the HTML is renders using that binding.

Comment: But the point is are all of the steps rendered at the same time (ie are you using individual objects for viewing each inside the widget) or does the widget represent each step along the way?  The reason I ask is it depends on how you want to render your content (are you using a singleton or what?)

Comment: @PWKad I am not sure I understand your question, but I will try to answer anyways: The steps are determined by the data-part markup inside the widget's container. The widget itself should only provide the wizard's UI experience, whatever goes on inside the actual steps is none of it's business. The widget only provides the user interface as well as the navigation mechanism (I use Knockout to make life easier for this as well). Sometime I'd like to add in some step validation hooks, but that's later. :)

Comment: @PWKad So every usage of the wizard will contain an initial set of steps (specified as data-part's, as shown in the question), but it would be cool to be able to add steps dynamically as well.

Comment: By using a foreach: binding I am assuming that all of the steps are shown regardless of logic.  If I were you and wanted to bind individual steps of the wizard to different control sets then I would not being doing it inside of a widget, I would be using the widget to display my step and calling it from a view.  What you are basically explaining would make me think that either you need to create singleton views for each step and render then or create a single widget to take care of each step along the way, and load up different data, but this should be called from a Wizard view of some sort

Comment: When initializing the widget, I grab all the data-part's with a selector: `[data-part^='step-content']`, this gives me all the step content parts defined by the widget user. I then iterate over them, generating a `Step` object for each step, and assign `step.content = $thisStepContent.html()` - once I've gotten all of the steps set up, Durandal renders the view, using the foreach binding to create my step headings and contents. I have a /widgets/wizard/view.html and viewmodel.js that takes care of rendering my wizard - the steps themselves are defined within each use of the wizard widget.

Comment: @PWKad So, say I had a "Setup Account" view, it would use my wizard widget, define it's steps - say, 1: Basic Information, 2: Some Other Step, 3: Finish - I then won't have to bother writing my entire wizard markup for each wizard I want to make, I simply define the steps inside the widget. If this doesen't make sense, could you create a quick fiddle showing your proposed solution?

Comment: Nope, that makes perfect sense now, your wizard widget isn't a singleton that is walking through a single process, it is a widget to re-use for multiple types of widgets.  I read you loud and clear now, give me a bit to post a solution you may be able to use

Comment: Sorry I have been really busy the last 2 hours have you looked @ this - http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Widget/  - specifically where it talks about overriding the HTML with bound observables?  A widget with a templated part override...

<div>
    <h1>Widgets Sample</h1>
    <div data-bind="expander:{items:projects}">
        <h2 data-part="header">Project: <span data-bind="text: name"></span></h2>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: @PWKad yes, that was where I started.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an implementation that uses a traditional Durandal master/detail approach in combination with a Tab widget. The tab widget only implements the tabbing functionality, while the Master controls what's pushed into it and the Detail controls the behavior/layout of itself.

### Master

#### Viewmodel

```
define(['./tab', 'plugins/widget', 'knockout'], function (Tab, widget, ko) {

    return {
        tabs: ko.observableArray([
            new Tab('Durandal', 'A ...', true),
            new Tab('UnityDatabinding', 'A ...'),
            new Tab('Caliburn.Micro', 'C ...')
        ]),
        addNewTab: function() {
            this.tabs.push(new Tab('New Tab ', 'A test tab.'));
        }
    };
});
```

#### View

```
<div>
    <h1>Tabs sample</h1>
    <!-- ko widget : {kind: 'tabs', items : tabs} -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <button class="btn" data-bind="click: addNewTab">Add</button>
</div>
```

### Detail

#### Viewmodel

```
define(['durandal/events', 'knockout'], function(events, ko) {
    return function(name, content, isActive) {
        this.isActive = ko.observable(isActive || false);
        this.name = name;
        this.content = content;
    };
});
```

#### view

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="html: description"></div>
</div>
```

### Tab widget

#### Viewmodel

```
define(['durandal/composition', 'jquery'], function(composition, $) {

    var ctor = function() { };

    ctor.prototype.activate = function(settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    };

    ctor.prototype.detached = function() {
        console.log('bootstrap/widget/viewmodel: detached', arguments, this);
    };

    ctor.prototype.toggle = function(model, event){
        this.deactivateAll();
        model.isActive(true);

    };

    ctor.prototype.deactivateAll = function(){

        $.each(this.settings.items(), function(idx, tab){
            tab.isActive(false);
        });
    };



    return ctor;
});
```

#### View

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: { data: settings.items }">
        <li data-bind="css: {active: isActive}">
            <a data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.toggle.bind($parent)"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" data-bind="foreach: { data: settings.items}">
        <div class="tab-pane"  data-bind="html: content, css: {active: isActive}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live version available at: http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#extras/default. Feel free to fork.

Comment: You tell me. Fork it/try it. If it's not working as you expect come back with a new question. BTW: If I understand the question correctly I'd start by trying to overwrite tab widget view `<div class="tab-pane"  data-bind="html: content, css: {active: isActive}"></div>` with `<div class="tab-pane"  data-bind="compose: $data, css: {active: isActive}"></div>` so that detail view controls what gets rendered.

Comment: if I use composition, I am forced to separate each step into a new view. I don't want that. :)

Comment: There you go... programming styles are different. If you find time create a small demo and send me a pull request. I'd be happy to show more than one approach.

Comment: The demo would pretty much be what I posted. :)

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, the problem with my bindings not applying, was due to the fact that I used the  `html` binding to set the step content. When Knockout sets the HTML, it does not apply bindings to it.

I wrote my own HTML binding handler, that wraps the HTML and inserts it as a DOM-node - Knockout will hapily apply bindings to this.

```
(function(window, $, ko) {
    var setHtml = function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var $elem = $(element);
        var unwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var $content = $(unwrapped);
        $elem.children().remove().end().append($content);
    };
    ko.bindingHandlers.htmlAsDom = {
        init: setHtml,
        update: setHtml
    };
}(window, jQuery, ko));
```

Please note, this only works when the binding value is wrapped as a node - e.g within a div tag. If not, it won't render it.

Comment: Have you considered of using a traditional master/detail design instead? There was a discussion about the concept at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850223/pass-a-viewmode-edit-add-to-the-durandaljs-wizard and I created an example at http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#master-detail/wizard2

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit No, however I've gotten this working the way I want, so I'm happy. :)

Comment: Why let the system work for you if you're able to do it own your own `;-)`.

Comment: @RainerAtSpirit Hahah, I hear ya :) - would using a master-detail like you proposed allow me to use my widget as pointed out in my question?

Comment: Good question that deserves a longer answer. Give it a try and let me know.